# http-kit websocket resolve symbol

Tags: clojure, http-kit

Problem:  I get a null pointer exception when I call the caller function in the below code if I pass it data via json from a javascript socket client.  I don't get the error when I run this same code from the repl and I pass it the same data i.e.

In repl:

```
(def data (json/write-str {:controller "hql" :function "something"}))
(caller data)
```

This works fine

From javascript: this gives me s null pointer exception when calling the function caller from the handler.

```
<script>
var msg = {'controller': 'hql','function':'something'};
socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.7:9090');
socket.onopen = function() {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
}
socket.onmessage = function(s) {
 console.log(s);
 socket.close();
}
socket.onclose = function() {
  console.log('Connection Closed');
}
</script>

(ns hqlserver.core
 (:use [org.httpkit.dbcp :only [use-database! close-database! insert-record update-values query delete-rows]]
       [org.httpkit.server])
 (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))

(defn hql [data]
 (use-database! "jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxx" "user" "xxxxx")
 (let [rows (query ("select username,firstname,lastname from users order by lastname,firstname")]
 (close-database!)
 (json/write-str rows)))

(defn get-controller [data]
 (if data
   (let [data (json/read-str data :key-fn keyword)]
     (data :controller))))

(defn caller [data]
  ((ns-resolve *ns* (symbol (get-controller data))) data))

(defn handler [request]
 (with-channel request channel
   (on-close channel (fn [status] (println "channel closed: " status)))
   (on-receive channel (fn [data] (send! channel (caller data))))))

 (defn -main [& args]
   (run-server handler {:port 9090}))
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve: Have a http-kit socket server running, connect via a javascript socket client.  Send the server a json string.  Parse the string to get a controller name and function and depending on the controller call different functions from the socket server to get database records.

Comment: Looking up a function to call within the scope of your entire namespace at runtime based on parsing JSON from a client is a bad idea. Consider that you can do the same thing with a hash map like `{:hql hql ...}` instead of the `ns-resolve` function, with the advantage that with a hash-map lookup you can at least have a whitelist of functions the client can make you look up and call. An example: if the client sent `{"controller" : "caller"}` they could make your server burn CPU until it hits a StackOverflow error.

Comment: Unfortunately the restriction is that what I will receive from the socket client will always be a json string.  I have no other option.  The problem here is that when I read the json string from the client I get an null pointer exception and can't call the function.  That is a requirement.  This error does not happen if I go to the repl and create the same json string and then run it via the functions.  That works ok, but not from the client.

Comment: my suggestion isn't not to take json from the client, it's to not use `ns-resolve` and instead look up the controller in a hash-map, so that you can whitelist. As to your problem, it's likely something not visible in this code, because as far as I can tell this should work. Double check that the json from the client is well formed, and double check that they keys you think are present are seen on the server side.

Comment: I get your point and it is well received.  However, I have checked that the json is correct and it is.  I don't know if it's something related with the socket  channel or something along those lines.  I keep getting this error:  [worker - 2 ] ERROR - handle websocket frame org.httpkit.server.Frame$TextFrame@134401b7 Java.lang.NullPointerException.  I can show the jason and the jason can be parsed correctly.  I can call the hql function and return the rows back to the javascript client with no issues.  The problem comes when I try to resolve the function and call it.  There I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best way but this is the solution:
Thanks to noisesmith for helping and tips....

```
(ns hqlserver.core
(:use [org.httpkit.dbcp :only [use-database! close-database! insert-   record update-values query delete-rows]]
    [org.httpkit.server]
    [hqlserver.s300.login :only [login]])
(:require [clojure.data.json :as json]
        [hqlserver.s300.site :refer [site-index site-update]]
        [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn get-site [data]
 (if data
   (let [data (json/read-str data :key-fn keyword)]
     (-> data :site))))

(defn get-controller [data]
  (if data
    (let [data (json/read-str data :key-fn keyword)]
      (-> data :controller))))

(defn get-function [data]
  (if data
    (let [data (json/read-str data :key-fn keyword)]
      (-> data :function))))

(defn caller [data]
 (let [site (get-site data)]
   (let [controller (get-controller data)]
     (let [function (get-function data)]
       (cond
         (and (= site "s300")(= controller "login")(= function "login")) (login data)
         (and (= site "s300")(= controller "site")(= function "site-index")) (site-index data)
         (and (= site "s300")(= controller "site")(= function "site-update")) (site-update data)
         :else (json/write-str {:error "No records found!"}))))))

(defn async-handler [ring-request]
  (with-channel ring-request channel
    (if (websocket? channel)
      (on-receive channel (fn [data]
                        (send! channel (caller data))))
      (send! channel {:status 200
                  :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
                  :body    "Long polling?"}))))

(defn -main [& args]
 (run-server async-handler {:port 9090}));
```